# absolute positioning of text and color

Tags: css

SO, three doubts for the output screen:

1. Why the text of "Well It is second " is showing instead of the color green wrapping it whole or the red color should cover the whole if it is the other way around?
2. Why the text of "Well It is second " overlaps the text "Well It is third" instead of other way around?
3. Why the "Well It is second " is not center aligned as I have specified other div tags to be?

Fairly new to web development, but I know what absolute positioning and relative positioning is.

https://codepen.io/nalingupta0/pen/

```css
div{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 100px;

}
.first{
    background-color: blue;
}
.second{
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
}
.third{
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="first " position: relative>Well It is first</div>
<div class="second">Well It is second </div>
<div class="third">Well It is third </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be some gaps of knowledge about absolute positioning.

An absolutely positioned `div` usually has the properties `top`, `right`, `left`, `bottom` associated with them. This way you can fine-tune where you place the div in the first ancestor `div` that has a `position: relative` assigned to it.

**Q1**: A `div` with `position: absolute` does not have an automatic width of 100%, instead it fits the content. You can change this by setting the width explicitely or by using `left: 0px; right: 0px;`.

**Q2**: An absolutely positioned element is always pulled out of the regular flow of content and placed before other `div`'s that are positioned as usual.

**Q3** The text is actually centered as you would expect, only the width is adjusted to fit the content, so you can't see it.